# Telling the extension of a file and echoing a certain value. (PHP/jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I've got a upload script that uses PHP (for upload), and jQuery for the progress bar. Here's the issue. I want it to only be allowed to have MP4s uploaded. It's working, I just need help to figure out how to fix the errors. See, if it isn't a mp4 it is supposed to echo `Only MP4s are allowed at the time.` elsewise, it will move the uploaded file to the users folder, then echo `Done. Want to see it on <a href=channelname>your channel?</a>`. Here's the issue. It won't echo out the errors. It just says "Done." whenever the file is done uploading. I would greatly appreciate help on how I can fix this.

Here's my code.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && !empty($_FILES["userfile"])) {
    $file_type = $_FILES['userfile']['type']; //returns the mimetype

   $allowed = array("video/mp4");
   if(!in_array($file_type, $allowed)) {
     echo "Only MP4 videos are allowed to be uploaded because of security, and this is still a beta.";
     echo "<button onclick='window.location.reload()'>Upload a different file</button>";
     echo "<script>removeDummy()</script>";
   } else {
      if (!file_exists($dir)) {
         mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
      }

      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],"videos/".$user."/".$_FILES['userfile']['name']);

      echo "Done. Want to see it on <a href='channelname'>your channel</a>?";
    }
}
```

and here's the jQuery and JS

```
function toggleBarVisibility() {
    var e = document.getElementById("bar_blank");
    e.style.display = (e.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
}

function createRequestObject() {
    var http;
    if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return http;
}

function sendRequest() {
    var http = createRequestObject();
    http.open("GET", "progress.php");
    http.onreadystatechange = function () { handleResponse(http); };
    http.send(null);
}

function handleResponse(http) {
    var response;
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
        response = http.responseText;
        document.getElementById("bar_color").style.width = response + "%";
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = response + "%";

        if (response < 100) {
            setTimeout("sendRequest()", 1000);
        }
        else {
            toggleBarVisibility();
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Done.";
        }
    }
}

function startUpload() {
    toggleBarVisibility();
    setTimeout("sendRequest()", 1000);
}

(function () {
    document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = startUpload;
})();
```

When it gets done, it says "Done." like in the jQuery. I want it to echo like the PHP does, not from the jQuery.

Comment: Put `response` in the `innerHTML`.

Comment: when I do that and it gets done it says "100"

Comment: You're sending a `GET` request, but PHP is testing if request method is `POST`, so the code isn't running.

Comment: The PHP code is also expecting a file to be uploaded, but you're not sending a file in JavaScript.

Comment: That PHP code doesn't seem to be intended for this AJAX request.